# Libgdx ShapeRenderer Performance

Tags: performance, libgdx, shapes

I am using libgdx currently and creating a game with only shaperenderer but there is a question in my head. Is begin and end methods drops fps because i use begin in every entity not just one begin for the rest of the game

```
public void render() {

    sr.setProjectionMatrix(Game.cam.combined);

    // Render Board
    board.render(sr);

    // Render Balls
    for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
        balls.get(i).render(sr);
    }

    // Render Players
    player1.render(sr);
    if (player2 != null) {
        player2.render(sr);
    }

    // Render Cannons
    downCannon.render(sr);
    if (upCannon != null) {
        upCannon.render(sr);
    }

    // Render Particles
    for (int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++) {
        particles.get(i).render(sr);
    }

    // Render BigRainParticles
    for (int i = 0; i < bigRainParticles.size(); i++) {
        bigRainParticles.get(i).render(sr);
    }

    // Render SmallRainParticles
    for (int i = 0; i < smallRainParticles.size(); i++) {
        smallRainParticles.get(i).render(sr);
    }

    // Render Gui
    gui.render(sr);
}
```

As you can see i am giving the shaperenderer to the entities. And inside the entities:

```
public void render(ShapeRenderer sr) {

    sr.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    sr.setColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    sr.line(x, y, ballX, ballY);
    sr.end();

    sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    sr.setColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    sr.circle(ballX, ballY, radius);
    sr.end();

    if (rect) {
        sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        sr.setColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        sr.rect(rectX - 5, rectY - 5, 10, 10);
        sr.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        sr.rect(rectX - 4, rectY - 4, 8, 8);
        sr.end();
    }
}
```

Any help about performence is appreciated :)

Comment: If you take a look at the source (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.java) you will see, that `end` calls `renderer.end()` wwhich makes the `renderer` flush it's stuff to the GPU, which is a pretty "heavy" operation. Therefore you should only call `flush` or `end` when it is absolutely neccessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the same ShapeRenderer Object for all your objects call begin at the beginning of the main render method and end at the end of it. So you call begin and end once.

The only reason you would want to end the ShapeRenderer earlier is if you wanted to draw with a different batch or Renderer which in your case it looks that you don't.

For example:
Usually I use scene2d and I have the stage batch in draw method. When I want to use the ShapeRender for primitive drawing I need to call batch.end() then shapeRenderer().begin -> draw stuff -> shapeRenderer.end() and finally batch.begin()